# ADD method in List does not work(List.add()) in flutter

Tags: flutter

`code`

```
Future<List<String>> getdetails() async {
    List<String> details;

    String user = await Auth.getcurrent(); //FirebaseUser()
    DocumentReference ref = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(
        '$user');
    DocumentSnapshot s = await ref.get();
    print(s.data['email']);    //This works
    details.add(s.data['email']);   //statements after this don't get printed
    print("bb");  
    print(details);  
    return details;
  }
```

The output for this is:
[only s.data['email'] gets printed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qkIi.jpg)

`print(s.data['email']);` works fine BUT `details.add(s.data['email']);` doesnt work and statements after this don't get printed.

To test this,after rearranging the statements,print statements after details.add() still do not work

```
 Future<List<String>> getdetails() async {
    List<String> details;

    String user = await Auth.getcurrent(); //FirebaseUser()
    DocumentReference ref = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(
        '$user');
    DocumentSnapshot s = await ref.get();
    print(s.data['email']);  //This works
    print("bb");                    //This works
    details.add(s.data['email']);      //statements after this don't get printed
    print("cc")   //This doesn't get printed
    print(details);  //This doesn't get printed
    return details;
  }
```

Output for this: [2 print statements get printed now instead of 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KAv1.jpg)

Comment: s.data('email') prints the email but when i pass it to details.add() it doesn't work.Also the statements after details.add don't get printed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you didn't instantiate your List and you invoke .add method on a null List.
Try

```
List<String> details = [];
```

instead of

```
List<String> details;
```

Comment: Worked fine.But shouldn't it throw an error when calling add on a null list.

Comment: yes it trow an error but not a fatal error, did you check your debug log?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but with the `List<T>.empty()`. It turns out that there is an optional parameter `growable` set to `false` by default. I set it to true and it works fine.